# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a `RecyclerView`, and in its adapter, I have created something similar to an `OnLongClickListener`, which I am calling an `OnEntryLongClickListener` to avoid confusion.

I am using an `AlertDialog` to display a dialog with list items for different actions. However, I am getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0  
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2345)  
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3910)  
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:2161)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:413)  
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)  
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.createListView(AlertController.java:734)  
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams.apply(AlertController.java:711)  
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:883)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.ThisActivity$2.onEntryLongClick(ThisActivity.java:135)  
    at com.mycompany.myapp.adapter.RVAdapter$RVViewHolder.onLongClick(RVAdapter.java:41)   
    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5236)
```

Below is the relevant code I am using:

```
adapter.setOnEntryLongClickListener(new RVAdapter.OnEntryLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEntryLongClick(View view, int position) {
        final MiniEntry thisEntry = entryList.get(position);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setTitle(thisEntry.getEntryName()););
        builder.setItems(R.array.quickActions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Other code here
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); // The error log points to this line
        alert.show();
    }
});
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As well as the XML I am using for the array:

```
<string-array name="quickActions">
    <item>Add to Favourites</item>
    <item>More information</item>
</string-array>
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but I am importing the `AlertDialog` from `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` (from the v7 Support Library).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Change `getBaseContext()` in the `AlertDialog.Builder` instantiation to the current Activity instance. For example, `new AlertDialog.Builder(ThisActivity.this)`.

Comment: @MikeM. This worked! Could you post this as an answer and *explain why  it solved the problem* as well - thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change `getBaseContext()` in the `AlertDialog.Builder` instantiation to the current `Activity` instance. For example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

An `AlertDialog` requires certain resources whose values are provided by the themes and styles attached to the `Context` it uses. The `Context` returned by `getBaseContext()` doesn't have those attached, but the `Activity` does. Indeed, whenever a `Context` is needed for a UI component - e.g., `Dialog`s, `View`s, `Adapter`s, etc. - the current `Activity` is usually what you want to use.

Comment: If I call this from within a fragment and use `getActivity()` I still get this error. Any ideas why?

Comment: saved a lot of time . Thanks

Comment: So when does one know when to use *Activity* or when to use *BaseContext*

Comment: @AdamMc331 For others looking for the answer to your comment.

Do something like

AlertDialog.Builder(context as HomeActivity)

Answer (score 26):

Try putting an style for your Dialog that extends Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert

`<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert" />`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

This works for me.

Greetings

Comment: Works for me too. Looks like a bug in the support lib to me.

Comment: For me the key was that, if I don't specify a theme like you suggest, the activity theme had to extend an AppCompat theme

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same issue as rupps

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, is only using Material Design Components without support library, you can use this constructor.

```
// in app build.gradle file 
// make sure you have the MDC depencency.
// https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${materialcomponents_version}"

// MainActivity.kt
// creating the builder
val dialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)

//... setting up dialog

// creating dialog successfully 
val alert: AlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
```